# SQLAnywhere: Savepoint for ROLLBACK not found

Tags: transaction, sybase-sql-anywhere, savepoint

What is the correct way on setting and rolling back to savepoint on SQLAnywhere. Having this snippet:

```
begin transaction;
SAVEPOINT spt_abc;
insert into eins (pl1) values (5);
SAVEPOINT spt_123;
UPDATE eins SET pl1 = 10 where pl1 = 5;
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT spt_abc;
commit;
```

Getting this error message while running it in dbisql:

> Could not execute statement. Savepoint 'spt_abc' not found SQLCODE=-220, ODBC 3 State="HY000" Line 6, column 1 You can continue
>   executing or stop.
>
> ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT spt_abc

the very same happens when trying to rollback to spt_123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour seems to be caused by the option to auto commit after each command in dbisql configurable via Tools->Options->SQLAnywhere->Execution->"Commit after every statement". If this option is set, I can reproduce the error described at the question. Unchecked it's working as expected.